# Replace css class with exact match in c# from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Replace css class with exact match in c# from code behind. Looks like btn1.CssClass.Replace() method does not perform exact match. Any other suggestions pls...

Comment: Explain your question more clearly.

Comment: I am changing css dynamically. btn1 having css class string as "GreenButtonShortDisabled divfloaleft". when i write following code btn1.CssClass.Replace("GreenButtonShort", "GreenButtonShortDisabled");  then changed css is "GreenButtonShortDisabledDisabled divfloaleft". I want whole word match.

Answer (score 0):

It's an HtmlGenericControl so not sure what the recommended way to do this is, so you could also do:

```
testSpace.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: center;");
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes.Add("class", "centerIt");
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes["style"] = "text-align: center;";
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes["class"] = "centerIt";
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: I am changing css dynamically. btn1 having css class string as "GreenButtonShortDisabled divfloaleft". when i write following code btn1.CssClass.Replace("GreenButtonShort", "GreenButtonShortDisabled"); then changed css is "GreenButtonShortDisabledDisabled divfloaleft". I want whole word match